# How accurate is an open-loop synchronous buck converter using gate driver IC?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, synchronous

I've designed a synchronous buck converter using a gate driver IC and two MOSFETs. I have 10 mH and 6.6 uF capacitor at the output as described in the attachment. I am providing 15 V as an input to the converter through connector P1. I am also running at 20 kHz of switching frequency. How accurate is the open loop measurement supposed to be? I expected about 7.5 V when I configure duty cycle wit 50% and ripple current & voltage to be around 1%. Load is fixed as 75 Ω. But the actual measurement of output voltage of the converter is around 6 V which is about 40% of input. I've tried to vary duty cycle but similar result. I don't get any closer value compared to my calculations and this gets worse when I increase duty cycle up to 70%. I do have a closed-loop with ADC then feed back to MCU later but I came across about this when I was testing an open-loop configuration. Is this expected behavior? Also, how should I remove the spike appearing at the switching node when turned on? Please see below for scope images.

**Expected (calculated) results with 20 kHz and 50% duty cycle :**

- I_out = 100 mA
- V_out = 7.5 V

**Open loop testing with no load result:**

- Yellow = switching node before inductor
- Blue = Vgs upper MOSFET
- Green = Vgs lower MOSFET
- No issue at the output. I see what I expected when there is no load.
  [image]

**With 75 Ω load with 50% duty cycle:**

- Yellow = node at output capacitor (after inductor)
- Red = inductor current
  [image]

**With 75 Ω load with increased duty cycle (62%):**

- Yellow = node at output capacitor (after inductor)
- Red = inductor current
  [image]

**Spikes at switching node before inductor:**

- Red = inductor current
- Yellow = voltage at switching node (before inductor)

[image]
[image]

Comment: If possible try to verify operation in CCM and not DCM. Can you add a sense resistor (say 10-100 m\$Omega\$ in series with your inductor, and take differential measurement across iit. In CCM, current through inductor will never fall to 0.

Comment: I will verify that. Thanks

Comment: 10 mH inductor @ 20 kHz sounds odd for 25 ohm load.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I have some scope measurements and updated in the post! It's clear that it is operating in CCM. So to my original question, am I supposed to see that amount of discrepancies in open-loop testing? I had to increase dome duty cycle to get desired output. Also, how should I remove spikes when switching node is turned on?

Comment: @Jens what's odd? I added some scope images in the post. Please have a look

Comment: You need a larger ripple current, minimum is 0.2 A peak within 25 µs, which requires < 937 uH. At higher values the average inductor current cannot reach the required load current. For your original approach with 10 V at 25 ohm load I would start with 220 µH.

Comment: @Jens Where are you getting 0.2A peak, 25us and 937 uH??

Comment: @Jens i am not aware of any maximum inductor value in this application. Is there a limit in general? I wanted to reduce the ripple so I used high inductance and that was based on general inductor calculations for buck converter application. I am able to achieve what I want with slight modifications on duty cycle. so I am not concerned about the original problem I had. I am just more confused as to where you got those values

Comment: Well, you are right, there is no upper limit, but 10 mH inductors with ISat around 0.3 A typically have around 10 ohm series resistance. I was worried about the slow response time of the later added regulator loop using such values.

Comment: @Jens Understood about your point in response time. Yes that's something I should be concerned but there is not requirement for now. Thanks for your input tho. Btw, where are you getting 0.2A peak, 25us and <937uH on the above comment?

Comment: I've reverted the last edit as it deleted essential context for understanding the question and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open loop and accuracy don't really go together.

With inductors often having 20% tolerances, on-resistances and switching speeds of transistors bring very temperature dependent and the properties of output capacitors not being much more precise, if say your 70% error is still much, but not unexpected. I would take a guess and assume you're using a model that neglects parasitics in the inductor and MOSFETs.

From the schematic, and in and output specs, I'd say designing this as open loop system is a mistake, even if you don't need accuracy. Feedback is essentially free in terms of circuit complexity and solves a lot of issues at once.

Comment: Hi Marcus Müller. Thanks for your reply. Yes, I don't have an intention to operate the system as an open-loop. I forgot to mention and attach rest of circuits but I do have mcu connected and read current through ADC then control the PWM.I just didn't have an experience in this design before and I was curious about the accuracy as an open-loop. I haven't tested along with mcu yet. Thanks again tho. But would you be able to elaborate what you mean by "I would take a guess and assume you're using a model that neglects parasitics in the inductor and MOSFETs"?

Comment: Such a large error between what you expect and what you measure can only be explained if your model of how your components behave is not modeling reality well enough. Typically, in such switcher applications, people neglect parasitic effects making MOSFETs switch slower and making inductors store less energy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be better than that.

- L value doesn’t matter
- C value doesn’t matter
- Mosfet/L/trace R does matter but should be low (verify)
- Mosfet switching times do matter but should be low (verify)
- Duty cycle obviously matters.  Verify this first

Most likely duty cycle isn’t actually 50% and/or your switching waveform is messed up for some reason.  Also possible you have R in the design you didn’t account for.

Should be easy to follow this circuit around and find the problem.  Switching waveforms should be nice and square (some overshoot allowed).

For context note that class-d audio amplifiers have the same topology (essentially) and no feedback and produce extremely linear response from duty cycle to output.

Comment: I tried all of your suggestion, specially checked all waveforms (Vgs of two mosfets and etc) and they seemed very clean waveform with the correct duty cycle of 50%. I tried with all different duty cycle. I can show you waveforms tomorrow.

Comment: Can you verify that it is _actually_ in CCM? Also, you could be losing voltage from your MOSFETs if for some reason they are not turning completely on.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy it's a synchronous converter so it never enters DCM.

Comment: @Andyaka that assumes the bottom transistor is working properly. IMHO, when troubleshooting it is always a good idea to verify that your assumptions are confirmed in reality.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy updated in the post! please have a look and let me know. thank you

Comment: @asdf30 I can confirm duty cycle is correct. Please see attached waveforms in the post. Nothings wrong with switching waveform.